# From Oracle to MS-Access to Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, ms-access

I have a client with close to 120,000,000 records in an Oracle database.  Their engineer claims they can only give us a ms access dump of their database.   The data will actually be going into an MySQL relational database instance.

What potential issues and problems can we expect moving from Oracle > Access > MySQL?

We have located tools that can convert oracle db to MySQL, but due the large nature of the database 100gb +  I am not sure of the stability of these software based solutions to handle the conversion process.  This is a time sensitive project and I am worried that if we make any mistakes in the onset that we may not be able to complete in a timely manner.

Comment: access has comparatively VERY limited field types v.s. oracle. unless the db has just basic int/char/varchar type stuff, you can probably expect some field mangling.

Comment: Access? With such a huge database? I'd be scared too...

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well marc and eternay

Comment: I'd see about having them dump a file of `INSERT` commands in MySQL syntax. You could probably cook up a query to do that. I'd also do the MySQL equivalent of `ALTER TABLE tbl_name NOLOGGING` before running the `INSERT` script. According to [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2958865/2091410) it's done with the `sql_log_bin` session variable.

Comment: 100GB in an Access database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exporting the Oracle data to a comma-separated, tab separated, or pipe separated set of files would not be very challenging. It's done all the time.

I have no idea why someone would claim to only be able to produce an MS Access dump from an Oracle database -- if that's not being done directly via selecting from Access through ODBC then it's done via an intermediate flat file anyway. I'm inclined to call "BS" or "incompetence" on this claim.

Comment: +1 this is your answer OP. Move the data to a flat file and then import that file. Ignore the access garbage.

Answer (score 3):

The [maximum size of an Access database is 2GB](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/access-2010-specifications-HA010341462.aspx) so I don't see how the proposed migration could be achieved without partitioning the data.